# Cant get dropbox populated with MYSQL database items

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying for ages to get this dropdown populated and it displays the items just not inside the dropdown.
Any ideas? :)

```
<?php 
     $html='';
     $html.='<select>';
     $queryExercise="SELECT exerciseName FROM workouts";
     $queryExercise=mysql_query($queryExercise);
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))
     {
      $exerciseName=$result['exerciseName'];
      echo '<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>';
     }
     $html.='</select>';
     echo $html;
    ?>
```

Comment: Post the generated HTML.

Comment: `print_r(mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))`. see what's the output

Comment: @Dherya the issue appears to be with the HTML, not the query.

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. It can only end in tears.

Answer (score 2):

Your Query **works perfect** but issue is concat the generated **dropdown** html.

As you are concating everything in **$html** so again you need to concate the result of dropdown to **$html** and then **echo $html**

Try **below code** :

```
<?php 
     $html ='<select>';
     $queryExercise="SELECT exerciseName FROM workouts";
     $queryExercise=mysql_query($queryExercise);
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))
     {
      $exerciseName=$result['exerciseName'];
      $html .= '<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>';
     }
     $html.='</select>';
     echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You missed to concatenate

`'<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>'` section.

```
<?php 
     $html ='<select>';
     $queryExercise="SELECT exerciseName FROM workouts";
     $queryExercise=mysql_query($queryExercise);
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))
     {
      $exerciseName=$result['exerciseName'];
      $html .= '<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>';
     }
     $html.='</select>';
     echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
<?php 
     $html='';
     $html.='<select>';
     $queryExercise="SELECT exerciseName FROM workouts";
     $queryExercise=mysql_query($queryExercise);
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))
     {
      $exerciseName=$result['exerciseName'];
      $html.= '<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>';
     }
     $html.='</select>';
     echo $html;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code also working fine

```
<?php 
 echo '<select>';
 $queryExercise="SELECT exerciseName FROM workouts";
 $queryExercise=mysql_query($queryExercise);
 while($result=mysql_fetch_array($queryExercise))
 {
  $exerciseName=$result['exerciseName'];
   echo '<option value="'.$exerciseName.'">'.$exerciseName.'</option>';
 }
 echo '</select>';
```

?>